# Hapi good how to print debug message without using console log

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm using hapi and good module
and I'm wondering what's the best way to
print my debug message without use
console log.

For instance now is

```
server.register(
    {
            register: require('good'),
            options: options
    },
    function (err) {
        if (err) {
                    return console.error(err);
            }
            // If the module is required by another script, we don’t start the server (ie test suite)
            if (!module.parent) {
                server.start(function () {
                console.info('Server started at ' + server.info.uri);
                    });
        }

    }
);
```

is it good using https://github.com/visionmedia/debug
like

```
server.register(
    {
            register: require('good'),
            options: options
    },
    function (err) {
        if (err) {
                    return console.error(err);
            }
            // If the module is required by another script, we don’t start the server (ie test suite)
            if (!module.parent) {
                server.start(function () {
                    debug('Server started at ' + server.info.uri);
                });
        }

    }
);
```

or there is a better options ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) is pretty good. Or, if you want to stay inside the hapi ecosystem, you can use [Good](https://github.com/hapijs/good) to manage your logging needs:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 4000 });

var options = {
    reporters: [{
        reporter: require('good-console'),    // Log everything to console
        events: { log: '*' }
    }, {
        reporter: require('good-file'),       // Log 'debug' to debug_log.log
        events: { log: 'debug' },
        config: 'debug_log.log'
    }, {
        reporter: require('good-file'),       // Log 'error' to error_log.log
        events: { log: 'error' },
        config: 'error_log.log'
    }]
};

server.register({
    register: require('good'),
    options: options
}, function (err) {

    if (err) {
        server.log(['error'], err);             // log an 'error' message
    }

    server.start(function (err) {

        if (err) {
            server.log(['error'], err);         // log an 'error' message
        }

        server.log(['debug'], 'Started...');    // log a 'debug' message
    });
});
```

Aside from logging to console there's a bunch of other "reporters" that let you log to HTTP, UDP etc:

https://github.com/hapijs/good#officially-supported-by-hapijs

Comment: How is this used inside the application?

Comment: Is this answer out of date? According to the documentation ```reporters``` requires key, value pairs: https://github.com/hapijs/good/blob/master/API.md#reporter-interface

Comment: Yeah the API has changed completely.